# overwriting existing animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

The parent div has two elements an image and a paragraph, on clicking (onclick event) the image the first animation runs
but now when I click on the "MORE" link the second animation should run moving the img and the paragraph in opposite direction and hiding the elements, but when clicking on the "MORE" link the second animation does not run.

CSS:

```
.dummy-wrapper {
                overflow: hidden;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                width: 45%;
                transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
                #info {
                    width: 300px;
                    display: hidden;
                    color: #fff;
                    transform: translateX(400%);
                    animation-duration: 1.5s;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                    text-align: justify;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    font-weight: 100;
                    .more {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        margin-top: 10px;
                        display: block;
                        color: orangered;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        font-size: 12px;
                        letter-spacing: 2px;
                    }
                    @keyframes info {
                        100% {
                            transform: translateX(0);
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                .bottle {
                    height: 200px;
                    width: 200px;
                    animation-duration: 1s;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    transform: translateX(60%);
                    transition: all 0.5s ease;
                    @keyframes bottle {
                        100% {
                            transform: translateX(0);
                            transform:  scale(0.4);
                        }
                    }
                }

                .removeBottle {
                    height: 200px;
                    width: 200px;
                    animation-duration: 1s;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                    @keyframes removeBottle {
                        100% {
                            transform: translateX(-300px);
                            transform:  scale(0.4);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

JS:

```
let bottleicon = document.getElementById("bottleicon"),
    info = document.getElementById("info"),
    morelink = document.getElementById("moreLink")

bottleicon.onclick = function() {
    bottleicon.style.animationName = "bottle"
    info.style.display = "block"
    info.style.animationName = "info"
}

morelink.onclick = function () {
    bottleicon.classList.add("removeBottle")
    bottleicon.style.animationName = "removeBottle"
}
```

In Dev tools the second transform:tranlateX(-300px) has a **strikethrough.**

How do I achieve the effect?

Comment: you first give transform: translateX(-300px) and then override it with transform: scale(.4). So only the  transform: scale(.4) will applied.

Comment: Try using transform: translateX(-300px) scale(0.4);

Comment: It seems like you are using saas not css.